# What does "Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 20.0.5594570." mean?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, synchronization

While synchronizing I see such warning.
Do I've to update my sdk tools?

What should I do to solve it?

Kindly help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it has been resolved by giving the path for NDK location.

Go to `File > Project Structure > SDK location` and then in the "Android NDK location" part, give your NDK address location. If you don't have it, you can download it.

How to download NDK:
`Tools -> SDK manager -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools -> NDK(side by side)`: Install it, if it's not installed